# i cant input values into a form directly from my data in the database

Tags: php, mysql

how do i get the value in the form input to be equal to the data fetched from my database . when i tried to retrieve the value from the post super global i got Array ( [john_doe] =>  ) i.e an empty value

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php while($subs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <input type="" name="john_doe" value='<?php echo $subs["menu_name"]; ?>'>
        <input type="submit" value="sumbit">
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: If we can't see the whole code, I don't see how we can help

Comment: can you print_r($subs)

Comment: var_dump($subs); and give us the results

Answer (score 0):

There will be some wrong with your database fetching, you can try this following code for your purpose

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "**YOUR QUERY**";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           <input type="text" name="john_doe" value='<?php echo $row["menu_name"]              ;?>'>
           <input type="submit" value="sumbit">
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```